# JBoss view active user sessions

Tags: jboss

We have a JBoss server with a single J2EE on it. I wish to find out who are the current active users using that application. Does JBoss give me any utilities that lets me view those existing sessions? (NOT the count, but who all are logged in) The question is kinda lame, but so is my JBoss knowledge :)

I checked the JBoss community, but it only had a couple of relative unanswered questions there. The information i'm looking for would help me in maintenance cycles. I do not wish to reboot the system when users are still using it. We also need to keep a track of any illegal activities on our server. Hence the requirement.

Would appreciate any pointers :)

Regards,

Abhi

Answer (score 1):

The closest I can offer is jboss's (really tomcat's) status page: http://yourhost:8080/status.  It shows the client IP address for all current sessions.

Anything more will depend on the nature of your deployed application.

Comment: Agreed, as JBoss doesn't really care about the identity of the connected peers other than for the network connection. Most likely application needs to somehow support this to find out anything more than that.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the all available sessions by using MessAdmin. Its a default tool with Jboss Application Server for administrator's help.Example for accessing Mess Admin shown below

http://192.168.18.31:8080/MessAdmin